# ionic - how to display information from a service in screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've loaded JSON data from API:

```
{
  "userGroups":[
    {"title":"group 1"},
    {"title":"group 2"},
    {"title":"group 3"},
    {"title":"group 4"}
  ]
}
```

I'm storing this raw data in NativeStorage.

```
// userService

this.userGroups        = response[userGroups];
this.current_userGroup = response[userGroups][0];

this.storage.set('userGroups',        this.userGroups);
this.storage.set('viewing_userGroup', this.current_userGroup);
```

So this way I have the entire list and the current item I want to display in app...

My question is how to access this information from my pages

```
<div class="page_title">{{ this.userGroupService.current_userGroup.title }}</div>
```

So, when I navigate to another userGroup, all I need to do is update `current_userGroup` to the new object...

Is this the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a service and `Subject` from `rxjs`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const title = new Subject<string>();
```

And when you want to update from the component:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService){
  this.myService.title.next('New Title')
}
```

To get value of it, you need to subscribe for it:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.title.subscribe(title => {
        console.log(title)
    })
}
```

You can change the type if it's not string.

Answer (score 0):

You must in html call some method that returns your current user group based on a page title if I understand.
First, you can create a map to your userGroups instead of a list, and create a method on service to return example:

```
Map<String, UserGroup> = new Map();
public getCurrentUserGroup(title):UserGroup{
  return userGroupsMap.get(title);
}
```

And call this method on html